# Multiple concurrent invocations of same query returning in same time as one invocation multiplied by the number of invocations

Tags: postgresql

When running the following query on Postgres 10 using a connection pool in a concurrent manner, the results return in n * the length of time it takes to run one invocation.

Tested in Racket using threads and Node with promises. Both return ~ the same timings in milliseconds.

1 invocation:
8322

10 invocations:

82432, 82260, 82025, 82260, 82432, 82103, 82025, 82556, 82040, 82119

Here is the query:

```
WITH contact_searches as (select
md.geo_point as md_point, md.sf_id as md_name, md.sf_id as md_sf_id, 
md.freehold_tenure as md_fh_ten,
md.freehold_search_price md_fh_sp, md.leasehold_tenure as md_lh_ten, 
md.leasehold_search_price as md_lh_sp,
md.special_tenure_search_price as md_st_sp, md.geo_point as point,
ss.freehold_tenure as ss_fh_ten, ss.leasehold_tenure as ss_lh_ten, 
ss.price_from as ss_pf, ss.price_to as ss_pt, md.marketing_trades as md_trades, 
ss.trades as ss_trades,
ss.sf_id as ss_sf_id, ss.person_id as person_id, ss.areas as areas
from saved_searches ss
inner join marketing_details md on md.marketing_trades && ss.trades
where md.sf_id = ANY ($1)
and
((md.freehold_tenure is not null  and ss.freehold_tenure ='true'
and (md.freehold_search_price is null or md.freehold_search_price >= ss.price_from)
and (md.freehold_search_price is null or md.freehold_search_price <= ss.price_to))
or
(md.leasehold_tenure is not null  and ss.leasehold_tenure ='true'
and (md.leasehold_search_price is null or md.leasehold_search_price >= ss.price_from)
and (md.leasehold_search_price is null or md.leasehold_search_price <= ss.price_to))
or
(md.special_tenure_search_price is not null
and (md.special_tenure_search_price >= ss.price_from)
and (md.special_tenure_search_price <= ss.price_to))
)
), contact_ids as (select distinct person_id as sf_id
from contact_searches inner join areas a on st_contains(a.polygon, contact_searches.point) 
where a.name = ANY (contact_searches.areas))
select c.sf_id, hasoptedoutofemail, preferred_contact_method, cco_email_opt_out, cf_email_opt_out,  valid_email(c)
from contacts c inner join contact_ids on c.sf_id = contact_ids.sf_id where c.applicant_status = 'Live'
```

Does anyone have any insight as to whether complex queries don't run in parralell or whether there is a config change I could make or anything else that could help?

Comment: The queries **will** run in parallel on the server **if** they are sent from different physical connections. One reason why an individual execution is so much slower could be that your server is simply overloaded (e.g. the harddisk's I/O is saturated or you only have 4 cores, not 10)

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name. Understood. The queries were run from different physical connections (ie a new explicit connection created for each invocation) however we are testing this on a smallish EC2 instance with four cores.

Comment: With four cores, the server can only handle four "really" concurrent queries, assuming that the storage system is able to cope with the additional load as well. Given your numbers I would assume that your I/O system simply can't keep up with the load of 10 queries